# Android-NDK : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), how to find error

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, signals, logcat

Good day lads. I'm issuing some problems with my Android application. I've been building and using C libraries (libcurl and my C files from tje JNI interface) with ups and downs but it was a smooth sail until today : while it sometimes works perfectly, sometimes it just crashes - yet finishes the series of C calculus it was tasked.

Basically I'm making series of URL calls with libcurl and analyze their results. From times to times, LogCat shows me the following (I ommitted some boring lines) :

```
11-26 15:47:04.930: I/DEBUG(4492): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
11-26 15:47:04.930: I/DEBUG(4492): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/GT-I9100P/GT-I9100P:2.3.6/GINGERBREAD/BVKL2:user/release-keys'
11-26 15:47:04.935: I/DEBUG(4492): pid: 9556, tid: 9568  >>> XX.XX.XX <<<
11-26 15:47:04.935: I/DEBUG(4492): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000034
11-26 15:47:04.935: I/DEBUG(4492):  r0 00000000  r1 47378718  r2 00000000  r3 00000000
11-26 15:47:04.935: I/DEBUG(4492):  r4 0000002c  r5 afd41544  r6 47523008  r7 00000000
11-26 15:47:04.935: I/DEBUG(4492):  r8 00010000  r9 0000002f  10 473787b4  fp 47378710
11-26 15:47:04.935: I/DEBUG(4492):  ip 47378698  sp 473786d0  lr afd17b77  pc afd2ea7e  cpsr 40000030
11-26 15:47:04.935: I/DEBUG(4492):  d0  0000000200000009  d1  3ff8000000000000
11-26 15:47:05.080: I/DEBUG(4492):          #00  pc 0002ea7e  /system/lib/libc.so
11-26 15:47:05.080: I/DEBUG(4492):          #01  pc 0002f456  /system/lib/libc.so
11-26 15:47:05.080: I/DEBUG(4492):          #02  pc 00030974  /system/lib/libc.so
11-26 15:47:05.080: I/DEBUG(4492): code around pc:
11-26 15:47:05.080: I/DEBUG(4492): afd2ea5c f8c40504 e69351c8 050268a0 9b03d417 
11-26 15:47:05.085: I/DEBUG(4492): afd2ea6c 98039a05 eb071899 463a0309 fcfaf7ff 
11-26 15:47:05.085: I/DEBUG(4492): code around lr:
11-26 15:47:05.085: I/DEBUG(4492): afd17b54 2074f5a0 0301f10a 7010f5a0 bfc89303 
11-26 15:47:05.085: I/DEBUG(4492): afd17b64 462a9004 46314638 f8cd464b f7f38000 
11-26 15:47:05.085: I/DEBUG(4492): stack:
11-26 15:47:05.085: I/DEBUG(4492):     47378690  47378718  
11-26 15:47:05.085: I/DEBUG(4492):     47378694  00000030  
11-26 15:47:05.085: I/DEBUG(4492):     47378698  473786a4  
11-26 15:47:05.085: I/DEBUG(4492):     4737869c  00000000  
11-26 15:47:05.085: I/DEBUG(4492):     473786a0  00000000
```

I understand this is a very generic problem and have been trying to locate the issue. I don't get how I could use the **ndk-stack** tool as **libc** is not part of the shared libraries I implemented but of the generic ones.

It would be pretty simple if the referred .so file was mine, but how can such an error popup ? If you have any idea on how I would be able to debug this, you'd be very welcome !

Comment: You can pull the library from the phone (adb pull /system/lib/libc.so) if you want to run e.g. objdump on it.

Comment: I tried already but I get the "bad file descriptor" error :/

Comment: you need to get that libc in one way or another. that's almost step 1.

Comment: Try to use add2line utility from NDK. It helps in many cases.